# On existence of a linear functional

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, linear-transformations

> Let $X$ be a vector space and let $Y$ be a proper subspace of $X$, and let $x∈X-Y$ Show that there is a linear functional $f$ on $X$ such that $f(x)=1$ and $f(y)=0$ for all $y \in Y$

I have already probed the result assuming that $X$ is a finite-dimensional space, but is it still valid if now $Dim(X)$ is infinite? I have tried to test it but I have not come up with anything correct, any comment or suggestion I will be very grateful

Comment: The argument for finite dimensional case works for infinite dimensional case also.

Comment: Do you need this linear functional to be continuous?

Comment: No i don't need the continuity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is to show that $X$ is a direct sum $Y\oplus \langle x\rangle \oplus Y'$. Then define $f(x)=1$ and $f(y)=f(y')=0$ for all $y\in Y$, $y'\in Y'$.

In order to arrive at the direct sum in the first place, you might need some version of the axiom of choice. You won't need it if you've already endowed $X$ with an inner product.